# php file upload strange error

Tags: php, file, upload

Why php give to me error of file upload?

```
<?php

   if($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1024*25*1024)
   {
     $message = 'file must be less, than 25 mb';
     exit;
   }

   if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
   {

     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "share/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);

     $message = 'succesfull!';
   } else {
      $message = 'Error upload file';
   }


?>
```

form with enctype = 'multipart/form-data'

in php.ini i have got

upload_max_file_size: 25 mb
Max_post_data = 25mb
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp

Why it does not work?

Comment: result is "Error upload file" , why?

Comment: Use `var_dump($_FILES);` instead of pointless `Error upload file` and see

Comment: If `is_uploaded_file()` fails, then PHP doesn't know why the upload failed. It just knows that it did. The only thing I can think of to check is that there is enough space on `/tmp`.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a print_r on $_FILES, you will see an error code. The meaning of the error code can be found here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: there is no error: array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "1326889022150.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpvS3WCa" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(35993) } }

Comment: The `name` of your file input is `file` or `filename`? If its the former, then change your above code to: `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` INSTEAD OF `$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']`

Comment: <div id="form">
        <form action = "upload.php" method = "post" enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
        Выберите файл:
        <input type="file" name="file" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" class="button red" value="Отправить файл на сервер" />
        </form>

Comment: Use `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

Answer (score 1):

**Verify that your php.ini setting looks like this:**

```
upload_max_file_size=25M
```

*Common Errors include:*

```
upload_max_file_size = 0.25M     // Must be an integer

upload_max_file_size = 25M       // No spaces around equal sign

upload_max_file_size=25MB        // Use M not MB

;upload_max_file_size=25M        // Semicolon in front comments out the line.
```

**Restart server after changing php.ini.**

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes

Answer (score 0):

if your content length is greater then max post size, you should use exception handler or you should put this code to top code.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && empty($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']) && substr($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'],0,19)=='multipart/form-data')
{
    if ($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']>1024*1024*25)
    {
        $message = 'file must be less, than 25 mb';
                exit;
    }
}
```